# Module-wise verbose logging in Google glog

Tags: c++, glog

I'm using Google [glog](http://code.google.com/p/google-glog/) for logging. I have a file in a directory with path `dir/file.cc`.

I want to enable verbose logging level 5 just in this file. So I export `GLOG_vmodule="file=5"` into the environment and then run the program. But glog still doesn't log the `VLOG(5)` messages in this file. Is there a problem with the way I'm setting `vmodule`? Can anyone give me an example of how this should be done?

Answer (score 1):

As specified [here](https://github.com/google/glog#verbose-logging) in the glog documentation:

> Verbose logging can be controlled from the command line on a per-module basis:
>
> `--vmodule=mapreduce=2,file=1,gfs*=3 --v=0` will:
>
> a. Print `VLOG(2)` and lower messages from `mapreduce.{h,cc}`
>
> b. Print `VLOG(1)` and lower messages from `file.{h,cc}`
>
> c. Print `VLOG(3)` and lower messages from files prefixed with "gfs"
>
> d. Print `VLOG(0)` and lower messages from elsewhere

Comment: Note that this only works with gcc compilers as noted in the glog source file vlog_is_on.h